# Difference between scroll and scrollTop in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between:

```
window.scroll(0,200);
```

AND

```
$(window).scrollTop(200);
```

Apart from the fact that one of them is using jQuery and the other is not, what is the difference? Does one animate the scroll and the other doesn't?  Will one work faster than the other?

Comment: Judging from [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d837f119c3729565103005d5d7fa89e1dd8110cb/src/offset.js#L174), `$.fn.scrollTop` essentially maps to `window.scrollTo`, which is essentially [the same as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo) `window.scroll`. Does that answer your question? )

Comment: As for performance, the usual considerations apply here - `window.scroll` is obviously faster (as the other method will invoke it after the several checks and function calls and object creations), but the difference will be negligible.

Comment: @raina77ow sorry, didn't mean to steal your answer, I didn't see your comments before answering

Answer (score 3):

.scrollTo() or .scroll() is applicable on window object while .scrollTop() works with any DOM element

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` uses `window.scrollTo`, it seems: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.scrollTop

Performance wise the pure js solution is faster, obviously, but in most cases it shouldn't really matter: http://jsperf.com/js-vs-jquery-scroll

There does not seem to be any differences in performance between `window.scroll` and `window.scrollTo`.

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery scrollTop() method - Returns the vertical scrollbar position for an HTML element
The JavaScript window.scroll(x-coord,y-coord) method scrolls the window to a particular place in the document. The window.scrollTo is effectively the same as this method.

Comment: There's a getter **and a setter** for `jQuery.scrollTop`